# fatal: could not create work tree dir 'ncorr_2D_matlab'

Tags: git, git-clone

I was trying cloning "https://github.com/justinblaber/ncorr_2D_matlab" in my Matlab folder as per instructions but got this error:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'ncorr_2D_matlab': No such file or directory
```

I even tried creating the directory but still got error:

```
Cloning into 'ncorr_2D_matlab'...
C:/Users/DHRUV DARDA/Documents/MATLAB/ncorr_2D_matlab/.git: No such file or directory
```

When I tried this in the User/'DHRUV DARDA'/Documents folder, I faced these errors above, but when I did the same in User/'DHRUV DARDA', it worked. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not cloning in a folder (`Documents/`) which could be synchronized automatically with a Microsoft OneDrive cloud storage service.
That would immediately mess up the repository which is trying to be created.

To confirm this, try and clone it in a simpler path (for testing)

```sh
mkdir C:\test
cd C:\test
git clone https://github.com/justinblaber/ncorr_2D_matlab
```